# What is this part of the wagon called?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a specific word for the name of the part of the wagon highlighted in red? This is towards the rear.

[image]

Comment: On a truck that's called a "tail gate".

Comment: A tailgate is hinged at the top? For the period, possibly a [**tailboard**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/tailboard).

Comment: @WeatherVane - The illustration (poorly) shows it hinged at the bottom.

Comment: @HotLicks, yes, that's exactly what I mean. I once had a little lorry with a hinged wooden flap at the back. It was called a tailboard. We only called them 'tailgates' when we had SUVs etc. and they completely closed the back, and usually hinged at the top.

Comment: Note that there are no doubt several terms for this -- UK vs US, eastern US vs western US, modern vs historical.  If you want a term for a novel, eg, you'd need to research the terminology used in the culture you're writing about.

Comment: @WeatherVane FYI, North American usage of "tailgate" is the thing on the back of a pickup truck that opens down. See also the American custom of "tailgating," which involves preparing food with a grill set up on the truck's open tailgate. This would be quite a feat on an SUV hatch!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On a Conestoga Wagon, the museum folks have it as a "rear end gate". See the third drawing, section c (labeled figure 10).

http://www.colonialsense.com/Society-Lifestyle/Signs_of_the_Times/Conestoga_Wagon/Parts_Identification.php

[image]

> Figure 10.—Details of the Freight-Carrying Wagon, 1800-1820, of Figure
> 8. (Drawing by Donald W. Holst.)
> a: Feedbox: 1, Top. 2, Side, showing pin and lug for securing to
> tongue. 3, End, showing bracket into which the chains hooked for traveling.
>
> b: Front end panel: 1, Bottom end rail. 2, Middle end rail. 3, Top end
> rail. 4, Standard, or upright, forming end framing. 5, End boards. 6,
> Bow. 7, Corner plates.
>
> c: Rear end gate: 1, Staples for end-gate standards. 2, End-gate hasps
> and hooks. 3, Pins to secure gate to upper side rails. 4, Crossbar to
> give extra support to end gate.
>
> d: Rear wheel.
>
> e: Cross section of wheel: 1, Boxings, of cast iron, wedged in hub to
> take wear of axle.
>
> f: Front wheel: 1, Felly, or felloe. 2, Spoke. 3, Hub, or nave.
>
> g: Floor of wagon, from under side: 1, Crossbeams, the center and rear
> ones being heavier, and projecting at the ends to hold the iron side
> braces visible in figure 8,a. 2, Bottom side rails. 3, Floorboards. 4,
> Position of rear bolster when bed is on running gear. 5, Front
> bolster, showing hole for kingpin.
>
> Source: Research and Text by Bryan Wright

Comment: I think this is the correct answer. There are a number of U.S. patents for end gates for wagons from the late 1800s to early 1900s (e.g. https://patents.google.com/patent/US665611). Also, there are companies that still sell the hardware for wagon end gates (e.g. https://www.hansenwheel.com/store/wagon-parts-supplies/buggy-wagon-part/wagon-parts/wagon-tailgate-swing-irons.html).

Answer (score 9):

My first thought for the answer was ***tailboard,*** and indeed that is attested:

> A hinged flap at the back of a truck that can be lowered or removed when loading or unloading the vehicle; a tailgate.
>
> > ‘A tailboard from a trailer was lost on Sunday, November between 8pm and 9pm on the Stradbally Road.’
>
> — [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/tailboard)

(Their definition of *tailgate* is actually identical, but then that particular bit has two names.)

Comment: Is this a UK term? I’m in the US, and I am unfamiliar with the the term tailboard.

Answer (score 3):

It is, as on many other vehicles, a tailgate.

For example See https://www.pinterest.co.uk/pin/428827195745127778/

Or http://www.davewilsonphotography.com/2015/05/30/covered-wagon-tailgate/

Comment: These don't really look like credible sources.

Comment: @KannE Thanks. I didn’t originally think it necessary to repeat links within links. Seems I was wrong.